# Prototype scriptaculous background-color: RGBA color animations

Tags: prototypejs, scriptaculous, rgba

Is something like this http://pioupioum.fr/sandbox/jquery-color/ for Prototype and scriptaculous?

I want to periodical animate RGBA for my website background to get something sexy and fancy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rgba` is pretty recent and [only supported by the newest browsers](http://css-tricks.com/examples/RGBaSupport/). Luckily these are pretty much the same browsers that also support [CSS transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) so no Javascript library is needed. Just look at this working example: [massiveblue.com](http://www.massiveblue.com/)

---

The [source](http://snipplr.com/view/33728/) explains it:

```css
body, #logo h1 a, ul#menu li.on {background-color: #39f !important;}
@-webkit-keyframes colours {
      0% {background-color: #39f;}
     15% {background-color: #8bc5d1;}
     30% {background-color: #f8cb4a;}
     45% {background-color: #95b850;}
     60% {background-color: #944893;}
     75% {background-color: #c71f00;}
     90% {background-color: #bdb280;}
    100% {background-color: #39f;}
}
body, #logo h1 a, ul#menu li.on {
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: colours;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}
```

The keyframes names "colours" as the sequence of frames, that is then used in `animation-name` rule. The `animation-iteration-count` is `infinite` so it loops continuously. Remember to duplicate the rules with each of the prefixes `-webkit-`, `-moz-` and `-o-` for the various browsers, and one set with no prefix for future compatibility.

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to StackOverflow too. If you use an answer it helps to tick the checkmark beside it, that marks it as accepted so others can see, and you get points for it too!

Comment: StackOverflow - realy awesome ;)